Mocking the headers in a response
I have looked at the comments on this question but they don't seem to tell me specifically what I need.
I am modifying this test, that previously only had to handle a single header:
    spyApiResolver.mockResolvedValue({
        response: {
            headers: headers: { get: () => mockHeaderValue },
        },
        json: mockApiResponse,
    });

So I assume this will return mockConnectionHeaderValue for any key.
That is to simulate this single header:
{ 'x-mycorp-headervalueone': mockHeaderValue }

How do I add another header to the mix so I can simulate THIS situation? Basically how do I make the mock return one header value for key x-mycorp-headervalueone and another for x-mycorp-headervaluetwo?
{ 'x-mycorp-headervalueone': mockHeaderValue, 'x-mycorp-headervaluetwo': mockOtherHeaderValue }


Use a real Headers object? Write the appropriate logic in the get method stub (note this is a bad approach because you're mocking something you don't own and coupling to an implementation detail you should be free to refactor around)?

Using a real Headers object:
    const mockedHeaders = new Headers();
    mockedHeaders.append('mycorp-headervalueone', mockHeaderValue);
    mockedHeaders.append('mycorp-headervaluetwo', mockOtherHeaderValue );

    spyApiResolver.mockResolvedValue({
        response: {
            headers: mockedHeaders,
        },
        json: mockApiResponse,
    });


FYI you can also do new Headers({ [name]: value, /* ... */ }) to initialise the object.

@jonrsharpe I was wondering if that would cause a new object to be created on each request?
